# How to add new columns of zeroes to a file?

Tags: python, bash, awk, addition, zero

I have a file of 10000 rows, e.g.,

```
1.2341105289455E+03 1.1348135000000E+00
```

I would like to have

```
1.2341105289455E+03 0.0 1.1348135000000E+00 0.0
```

and insert columns of '0.0' in it.

I tried to replace 'space' into '0.0' it works but I don't think it is the best solution. I tried with awk but I was only able to add '0.0' at the end of the file.

I bet there is a better solution to it. Do you know how to do it? awk? python? emacs?

Comment: Hi Jesus. For this type of question, it would be good to post some of your failed solutions. They may be the basis for the solutions that members decide to offer.  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", $F[0], "0.0", $F[1], "0.0"; ' in_file > out_file
```

The perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**

[perlrun: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`

```
awk '{print $1,"0.0",$2,"0.0"}' file
```

If you want to modify the file inplace, you can do it either with `GNU awk` adding the`-i inplace` option, or adding `> tmp && mv tmp file` to the existing command. But always run it first without replacing, to test it and confirm the output.